# Multidimensional Scaling - distance?

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis

I am trying to plot a ggscatter plot with a 8 variables and 72 rows, and i am following the steps in the reference (at the bottom as a link). However, the author label the x-axis and the y-asix as dim1 and dim2. What does it exactly mean? The distance? If so, if the plot shows 2 distinct points on the bottom, it indeed means they are somewhat different than the other plots; but there are 8 variables, how do i know which variables make them different?

Reference:
http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/122-multidimensional-scaling-essentials-algorithms-and-r-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method collapses the information of multiple columns into fewer. In that specific example, 6 columns from the Swiss dataset is collapsed into two columns/variables.

Dim1 and Dim2 stands for dimension 1 and dimension 2. Thus the distances between the points from 6 dimensions (variables) are now in 2 and thus can be visualised.

Now, if you identify an outlier point in the plot you can then go back to the original dataset and identify why this point is indeed an outlier in many ways. In this example, I would identify the variables by looking at which variables yield the largest proportional difference:

From the plot in the example, "V. De Geneve" seems to be an outlier. Let's see why:

```
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
# Average of value of each variable in the dataset
x1 <- swiss %>% summarise_all(mean)
# Average of value of each variable in the dataset excluding the outlier 
x2 <- swiss %>% filter(rownames(swiss) != "V. De Geneve")  %>% summarise_all(mean)

# Let's see which variables have the highest difference before and after excluding V. De Geneve
abs(1 - (x1/x2))

# Fertility Agriculture Examination Education     Catholic  Infant.Mortality
# 0.01077431  0.02078308  0.02779219 0.0907587 0.0006324191      0.002113079
```

From the above, it seems that this person changes the average mostly for Education, followed by Examination and Agriculture. Indeed:

```
swiss %>% summarise_all(mean)
# Fertility Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
# 70.14255    50.65957    16.48936  10.97872 41.14383         19.94255
swiss %>% summarise_all(sd)
# Fertility Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
#  12.4917    22.71122    7.977883  9.615407 41.70485         2.912697
swiss %>% filter(rownames(swiss) == "V. De Geneve")
# Fertility Agriculture Examination Education Catholic Infant.Mortality
#       35         1.2          37        53    42.34               18
```

If you take a look at the dataset's average and standard deviation overall stats, you will see that this person is far away for these variables. For instance for education he is 4 standard deviations away from the mean (even with him inside the calculations)

Comment: if the 6 columns collapse into 2 columns; if there's an outlier, how can i know which variable makes the point as outlier?

Comment: Let me edit the answer and add that with an example it R